# Machine Learning: What's the best way to detect the type of an event

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have several question regarding machine learning algorithm. (I'm new to it)
Can a ML algo determine the type of a specific event ? For example, I pull an event from Facebook and the algorithm detect that it's a music event.
NLP algorithm seem to work (fasText) in that case, by training the algorithm before with good data and linking the type of the event with the description of it. 
Is there a better algorithm for this work ?
Another question, in the case where I want the algorithm to give me multi type of event. For example an event that can be related to multiple tag such as a Conference and Tech.
What can be the best solution to implement this ?
What kind of framework can be the best ?

Thank you,

Comment: You are not really asking a question. Please advance on your project and come back with a precise, testable technical problem and show what you tried and the results you had.

Comment: Hello Clement, thank you for your response
I'am just in a "thinking phase", so there haven't a project. I'm studying the possibility on this problem. What's the best ML Algorithm for this matter ?

Comment: "Best ML algorithm" and "best framework" depend on details that don't appear in your posting.  SO is for more specific problems.  You're asking for a discussion over your current exploration space.

Answer (score 0):

I have done several thing to test what I was saying and it's seem to work.

I have scrap event from Facebook and manually assign them tags (such as basketball, conference etc..)

I have normalise the data I got.

Used fasttext to train in a supervised way (with a high learning rate because I don't have enough data).

And so far, the result I get are pretty good. The model is able to guess accurately the tag of an event I gave him.

I don't know if fasttext is still the best tool to do what I'have done but still it work as intended.